# Angular custom form components and clearValidators

Tags: angular

I'm implementing custom form components that works with template and model driven forms, using NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR and NG_VALIDATORS for custom validator. All works fine but when i clearValidators also my custom validators are removed. How can i prevent my custom validators cancellation in components ?